# How can I automatically do vagrant up every time my OSX machine boots?

Tags: macos, vagrant

I need a way to automatically do a `vagrant up` command inside my directory */Users/user/Dropbox/Development/Homestead*

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: The Apple way to do these things is to use `launchd` and `launchctl`. It is not too difficult, and you can adapt this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076493/making-mac-osx-launchctl-launch-a-process-as-root-on-startup

Answer (score 4):

You can write an automator application (i.e. workflow) and in that application have it run the shell script with your desired vagrant command. Then go to System Preferences -> Accounts -> Login items and add that application as a login item.

[image]

Comment: I believe this will start vagrant when the user logs in which may be some considerable time after system boot which is what the OP requested.

Comment: Not OP, but works perfectly for my needs, and I don't mind this happens after login.

Answer (score 2):

With a LaunchD item. Put a file containing this in your /Library/LaunchDaemons directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>UserName</key>
 <string>user</string>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>org.xyzzy.vagrantsrc</string>
 <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
   <dict>
     <key>PATH</key>
     <string>/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
   </dict>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
    <string>/usr/bin/vagrant</string>
    <string>up</string>
 </array>
 <key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>
 <key>UserName</key><string>jenkins</string>
 <key>WorkingDirectory</key><string>/Users/user/Dropbox/Development/Homestead</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It needs to be owned by root and called something.plist